# What could be a reason why a root element might not be specified in the attempted creation of an XML using a ImDTD through eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, dtd

I'm trying to create an XML file containing information on a list of books using elements created in a DTD file, all elements have been referenced correctly(i think?). An error prompts when I try to create an XML file using the elements from the DTD claiming; "A root element must be specified". Is there an issue with my code or is it possible, although unlikely, its an issue with Eclipse (i.e. unsuitable version, missing plugin)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT bookList(book)*>
<!ELEMENT book((author | editor, contributors+), title, publisher, isbn_num, price, vol?, edition?)>

<!ELEMENT author(#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT editor(#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT contributors(#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT publisher(#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST isbn_num id_code ID #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT price(#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST price currency (GBP | EUR | USD) #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT vol(#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT edition(#PCDATA)>
```

Verion used: Eclipse Java EE IDE, Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1)

Comment: What command exactly are you using to try to create a document?  Does that command expect an element type name for the root element as a parameter?  Does it expect the DTD to take the form `<!DOCTYPE booklist ...>`?

Comment: What exactly are you doing with this DTD when you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML needs a root element, and link to the DTD file. Something like this would be the end result for an external DTD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "file.dtd">
<root>
<element1>a</element1>
<element2>b</element2>
<element3>c</element3>
<element4>d</element4>
</root>
```

"root" could be anything you want.

It looks like you are making an external DTD, in which case, your file does not need the XML definition.

```
<!ELEMENT bookList(book)*>
<!ELEMENT book((author | editor, contributors+), title, publisher, isbn_num, price, vol?, edition?)>
<!ELEMENT author(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT editor(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT contributors(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher(#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST isbn_num id_code ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT price(#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST price currency (GBP | EUR | USD) #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT vol(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT edition(#PCDATA)>
```

If you were trying to make an internal DTD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bookList [
<!ELEMENT bookList(book)*>
<!ELEMENT book((author | editor, contributors+), title, publisher, isbn_num, price, vol?, edition?)>
<!ELEMENT author(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT editor(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT contributors(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher(#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST isbn_num id_code ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT price(#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST price currency (GBP | EUR | USD) #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT vol(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT edition(#PCDATA)>
]>
<bookList>......</bookList>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spaced out your code and it doesn't show the error. For example, I spaced "bookList(book)" into "bookList (book)". See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT bookList (book)*>
<!ELEMENT book ((author | editor, contributors+), title, publisher, isbn_num, price, vol?, edition?)>

<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT editor (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT contributors (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST isbn_num id_code ID #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST price currency (GBP | EUR | USD) #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT vol (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT edition (#PCDATA)>
```

Hope this helps